# finding the least nonnegative residue

Tags: congruences, congruence-relations, reduced-residue-system

I do not really understand how to find the least non negative residue for an integer n mod m. Can you anyone explain to me with an example how to do it?

Comment: Least nonnegative residue of $n$ mod $m$ is literally the remainder you get when you divide $n$ by $m$.  For example, the least residue of $30$ mod $7$ is $2$.

Comment: @D_S okay so if I am asked to find the least nonnegative residue for n =3^1000 and m= 7 how would I approach that?

Comment: There are many ways. One approach would be to use Fermat's little theorem, which says that $3^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7$

Comment: @joeb would that be my final answer? or should I reduce it more ? is another way ? like with more steps and more algebra?

Comment: No, that would only tell you the least non-negative residue for $3^6$, not necessarily for $3^{1000}$. You should use the property that, modulo $m$ if $a \equiv b$ then $a^k \equiv b^k$. For instance, $3^{12} = (3^6)^2 \equiv (1)^2 = 1 \mod m$. Can you see how to chew away at $3^{1000}$?

Comment: Hint: $1000 = 6 \cdot 166 + 4$

Comment: @joeb I think these are enough to get me started.Thank you!